# Context Free Grammar clarification

Tags: shell, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree, context-free-grammar, recursive-descent

I created the following grammar for a minishell, but i realized that the parser never goes to `command_p`, it only stays at `cmd_prefix`.
Can somebody please clarify for me since i've seen a similar grammar in the [official shell grammar](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/xcu_chap02.html)

```
command         : cmd_prefix command_p
                ;

command_p       : cmd_name cmd_suffix command_p
                | ε
                ;

cmd_prefix      : io_redirect cmd_prefix
                | word cmd_prefix
                | ε
                ;

cmd_name        : word
                ;

cmd_suffix      : io_redirect cmd_suffix
                | word cmd_suffix
                | ε
                ;
```

I tried to make a simpler grammar than the official shell grammar for Recursive Descent parser, but later on i found out that maybe there is no need for the other rules since `cmd_prefix` keeps calling itself recursively.

Comment: From what I see, `cmd_prefix` can expand to any sequence of `word` and/or `io_redirect`. Since the whole shell input line consists of words and io-redirects, this would consume everything.